# Remove item from session onClick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove an item from a sort of shopping cart. The items are saved to a session when they are "saved to the shopping cart".

But now I would like to be able to remove certain items from this "shopping cart". Because I got the script from here (stackoverflow) I'm not that familiar with the code. I saw some answers on google and here that described using `unset` to delete the entry from the session. But I wouldn't know where to start with this one. If additional information is needed please let me know. Thanks for having a look at my question...

Here is the HTML (nothing special):

```
<div class="txtHint"></div>
```

This is my script:

```
$('.add-product').click(function() {
        var productName = $(this).data('product');
            $.post('example.com/reload.php', {productName: productName}, function(data) {
            $('.txtHint').html(data);
        })
    });
```

This is my reload.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!array_key_exists('products', $_SESSION) || !is_array($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $_SESSION['products'] = [];
}

$productName = array_key_exists('productName', $_POST) ? (string) $_POST['productName'] : '';

if ($productName) {
    $_SESSION['products'][] = $productName;
}
?>

<h4>Saved Items</h4>
  <?php foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product): ?>
    <div class="echo-product"><i style="color:#F60;padding-right:20px;" class="fa fa-anchor" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Updated code: As suggested by Bert Maurau (I Hope).

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!array_key_exists('products', $_SESSION) || !is_array($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $_SESSION['products'] = [];
}

$productName = array_key_exists('productName', $_POST) ? (string) $_POST['productName'] : '';

if(isset($_GET['delparam'])){
   unset($_SESSION['products'][$productName]);
}
if(isset($_GET['addparam'])){
    $_SESSION['products'][] = $productName;
}
?>
```

If I use this it doesn't add any new items...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a variable from a PHP session array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231332/how-to-remove-a-variable-from-a-php-session-array)

Comment: To remove a product you should compage if your requested product is in your array and remove it. Something like that:

`if($_SESSION['products'][$_POST['productName']] == $_POST['productName']) {
 unset($_SESSION['products'][$_POST['productName']]);
}`

To be more easy you should create some controller for each action. Like add, delete, etc...

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that this isn't my code. So I don't know where to add controllers and such. But I will look in to you answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
unset($_SESSION['products'][$productName]);
```

This wil unset the array_key and its values that matches your productName.

***Edit: Code for using the unset***

HTML:

```
$('.delete-product').click(function() {
  var productName = $(this).data('product');
  $.post('example.com/reload.php?delparam', {productName: productName}, function(data) {
  })
});
```

Reload.php (after $productName)

```
if(isset($_GET['delparam'])){
   unset($_SESSION['products'][$productName]);
}
if(isset($_GET['addparam'])){
   //code for adding product
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I place your bit of code in my `reload.php` file? And how do I use the unset to react to a button click?

Comment: Could you please look at my updated code in my OP? @Bert Maurau. I'm probably being a real noob here..

Comment: That should work. You just have to edit your .add-product call to:
$.post('example.com/reload.php?addparam'

Comment: Hi Bert Maurau, I did what you said and changed the .add-product to `reload.php?addparam` but it did not "save" the item.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you get any output if you put a die(var_dump(..)) of your session/post in your addparam check to make your sure it gets called?

Comment: Hi Bert, Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: If I look at my console I do see this: `POST 
XHR 
http://example.com/reload.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 42ms]
`

Comment: Ok it adds the Item now. But it does not delete it when I click the button. HTML of the button: `<a href="#" class="delete-product">x</div>`

Comment: If you still would like to see a var dump: `array(2) { ["Item Z"]=> string(6) "Item Z" ["Ivan Frank"]=> string(10) "Ivan Frank" }`

This is selecting 2 items @Bert Maurau

Comment: If you do var_dump($_SESSION['products'][$productName]) you should get your desired value. Also, with your delete <a> did you also add the required onClick code that calls the reload.php?delparam ? Because the above code should do the trick