# Remove one variable from a PHP session

Tags: php

I Would like to remove a variable from a PHP session array when the user chooses 'Remove'.

But when I unset, ALL the variables in the array are deleted.

How I can delete just one variable?

```
    <?php

session_start();

if (!array_key_exists('products', $_SESSION) || !is_array($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $_SESSION['products'] = [];
}

$productName = array_key_exists('productName', $_POST) ? (string) $_POST['productName'] : '';

if(isset($_GET['delparam'])){
   unset($_SESSION['products'][$productName]);
}
if(isset($_GET['addparam'])){
    $_SESSION['products'][$productName] = $productName;
}
?>

  <?php foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product): ?>
    <div class="echo-product"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); ?>
     <button type="submit" class="delete-product" value="Remove" >[x]</button>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach;?>
```

My code is a bit different from the other posts I found on this site. But I really need help with this code...

**Update**

```
$('.add-product').click(function() {
    var productName = $(this).data('product');
        $.post('http://examp.nl/reload.php?addparam', {productName: productName}, function(data) {
            $('.echo').html(data);
    })
});

$('.delete-product').click(function() {
    var productName = $(this).data('product');
        $.post('http://examp.nl/reload.php?delparam', {productName: productName}, function(data) {
            $('.echo').html(data);
    })
});
```

**Update**
If I use the following dump 
`var_dump((unset) $productName);
var_dump($productName);`

I get this output. Maybe it is of help...
`NULL string(6) "Item Z"`

Comment: See my update @Epodax

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['products']);

Comment: console.log(data);

Comment: what is the output of these?

Comment: Var_dump: `array(1) { ["RAW Ferry"]=> string(9) "RAW Ferry" } `

Comment: Console.log:`ReferenceError: data is not defined` and then a whole list of jquery msg @AmitRajput

Comment: `<anonymous>
 jquery.min.js:10
.globalEval()
 jquery.min.js:2
ua()
 jquery.min.js:3
.append()
 jquery.min.js:3
.html/<()
 jquery.min.js:3
K()
 jquery.min.js:2
.html()
 jquery.min.js:3
<anonymous>
 myowncode:420
n.Callbacks/i()
 jquery.min.js:2
n.Callbacks/j.fireWith()
 jquery.min.js:2
z()
 jquery.min.js:4
.send/c/<()
 jquery.min.js:4
 jquery.min.js:10:1`

Comment: Check out this post:
[How to remove a variable from a PHP session array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231332/how-to-remove-a-variable-from-a-php-session-array) Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks @JustIce But I had a look at that post. But it didn't help me... to bad.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the session use

```
$_SESSION['user']=array();
```

The array contains the full data as your more than one values with key and values combinations
then remove as follows:

```
unset($_SESSION['user']['index_name']);
```

Comment: My code now creates a session like this: `$_SESSION['products']=array();`

Comment: Unset is now: `unset($_SESSION['products'][$productName]);`
`$productName` is: `$productName = array_key_exists('productName', $_POST) ? (string) $_POST['productName'] : '';`

Comment: Still no go @PHP Geek

Answer (score 0):

An altenative would be to define a boolean 'productOption' variable, 0 = remove and 1 = add, then your .delete-product would look lie this:

```
$('.delete-product').click(function() {
var productName = $(this).data('product');
var option = 0; 
    $.post('http://examp.nl/reload.php?delparam', {productName: productName, productOption: option}, function(data) {
        $('.echo').html(data);
})
```

Then inside your reload.php script, you verify if the variable isset and then unset the specific session variable you are after.

I've not tried this code yet but please try it and let me know if it works;

**EDIT**

if you have defined a $_session['product'] variable, then it will hold all the products listed. Think of it as a multidimensional array.

Comment: Where do I get the `[$key]` from?
`array(3) { ["Boot X"]=> string(6) "Boot X" ["Boot Y"]=> string(6) "Boot Y" ["Boot Z"]=> string(6) "Boot Z" } ` @Just Ice

Comment: Don't I already know what the `$key` should be with this code: `$productName = array_key_exists('productName', $_POST) ? (string) $_POST['productName'] : '';`

Comment: So how do I target the specific product name to be removed from the full list of selected products.