# how do I remove an empty key completely from $_SESSION array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, session, cookies, destroy

I start the session by following command:

```
session_start();
```

when the user logs in I save information of that user in the `$_SESSION`
with following code:

```
$_SESSION["logged_in_user"]=$username;  
$_SESSION["logged_in_status"]="logged in";
$_SESSION["logged_in_business_id"]=$business_id;
$_SESSION["logged_in_business"]=$business_name;
```

and when the user logs out I do the following commands to clear the `$_SESSION` :

```
setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", time()-3600, "/" );
$_SESSION=array();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
```

Now when I check the `$_SESSION` after logout and before login, the result is an empty array(), which is exactly what it should be. But as soon as I log in `$_SESSION` not only shows the information I saved in it, but also empty values with filled keys, like for example:

```
Array(
[logged_in_user] => aristocraticmasterminder
[logged_in_status] => logged in
[logged_in_business_id] => us-000000001
[logged_in_business] => Microsoft PLC Limited
[RoleID] => 
[RoleName] => 
[RoleDuty1] => 
);
```

These keys do not have any value saved in `$_SESSION` corresponding to them. I `session_start();` on the top of each page, and consequently also on the log out page before `session_destroy();` I think this has something to do with the PHPSESSID cookie which is saved on my browser. How can I clear these empty keys and just save the data saved after the `session_start();`?

Comment: Did you `session_start();` before `$_SESSION=array();
session_destroy();` when they logout?

Comment: yes I session_start(); before log-in and session_destroy(); during logout

Comment: Can you show minimal working example code?

Comment: No, you must call `session_start()` when they logout, before `$_SESSION=array();
session_destroy();` or there is no `$_SESSION` array and no session to destroy.

Comment: I do that aswell, I session_start(); on the top of each page, and consequently also on the log out page before session_destroy();

Comment: can we please see some sample code?

Comment: I have edited and updated the code which saves the user details into $_SESSION

Comment: In what part of your code are you setting those session keys that now turn up empty? Try and put a debug output statement there (resp. a break point, if you have an IDE with the ability to debug), and see if not maybe that code gets run through during/after login as well.

Comment: I am not setting those keys, they were set a few days ago, when those pages were under construction. But after new login or even after new server restart, i didn't touch them. That is why they are empty.

Comment: _"That is why they are empty"_ - so they _were_ the empty the last time they were used? // You are just using the default PHP session mechanism here, no frameworks with their oven session handler or something like this?

Comment: @CBroe No when empty keys are used by the system in $_SESSION they have value corresponding to them, and that is done by a totally different page, which has not been touched as soon as I log-in.

Comment: Did you or did you not _verify_ that in the way I suggested?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135893/discussion-between-rabia-rana-khan-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
```

[How to remove a variable from a PHP session array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231332/how-to-remove-a-variable-from-a-php-session-array)

Comment: does this mean that I have to clear all the variables from $_SESSION array like this. There are a lot of variables I stored in $_SESSION and if so, then what is the need for session_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your session destruction sequence.

Change:

```
$_SESSION=array();
session_destroy();
```

To:

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION=array();
```

Comment: nope it didn't work aswell. I think it has something to do with PHPSESSID cookie, Do you know how can I make that cookie to expire?

Comment: Thats bugging me.. if you set $_SESSION to an empty array, everything should be gone! what happens if you unset($_SESSION)?

Comment: I researched it, it has something to do with the PHPSESSID cookie. Can you tell me how to make it expire. Example is here: http://7php.com/php-5-3-how-to-completely-destroy-session-variables-in-php

Comment: @RabiaRanaKhan check the manual for session_destroy, it's explained there how to delete the session cookie.

Comment: Although I doubt that's really it. PHP should only be able to pick up the now empty session with the same id, _because_ of the call to session_destroy.

Comment: @CBroe then why are those empty keys appearing. and how do I clear them?

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible with the code shown so far. Check what happens when you clear the session cookie (or all cookies for the site, to be sure), and then go through the steps again. If those keys are appearing in a "fresh" session with a new id ... then something in your code must be setting them.

Comment: @CBroe I deleted all the cookies from the browser, but still the empty keys are appearing. I don't know why?

Comment: That is all the more reason to believe that they get set somewhere in your code ... they can not magically appear out of thin air in a fresh session.