# This login success welcome,(email) keep showing after I logged in, is there any way to show it only once? even when I reload like it will disappear?

Tags: php

```
<?php
        session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["Email"])) 
    {
           echo '<h1> Login Success, Welcome - ' . $_SESSION["Email"]. '</h1>';
    }
?>
```

This login success welcome,(email) keep showing after I logged in, is there any way to show it only once?
even when I reload like it will disappear? I want this looping to stop please help me.

Comment: Just add `unset($_SESSION['Email']);` in the `if` block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a variable from a PHP session array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231332/how-to-remove-a-variable-from-a-php-session-array)

Comment: Why is that tagged as `mysql`?

Comment: `please help me ASAP! TY!` your question is not more important then any other question.

Comment: I would prefer to set another session variable like `$_SESSION["msgShown"] = true;` And have it in `if (isset($_SESSION["Email"]) && !isset($_SESSION["msgShown"]))`