# How to delete a Session Cookie

Tags: php, session-cookies, logout

after a lot of research i coulndt find a way for getting my dream come true.
Im currently making a cloud hosted on m< "localhost" (will get online someday) and implemented only one Cookie for remember Users after logged in. I need a way to logout through button for my users but theres the problem i couldnt find any way that fits my "case". I already tried to change the date of the cookie and a lot of methods where they delete the Cookie but it never worked, it could be the problem that a Session Cookie dont have a expiration date. The Cookie name is always "PHPSESSID" it will get created after logged in:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("db.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['code'])){
  $code = $_SESSION['code'];
  $saftycode = $db_link->real_escape_string($code);
  $check = 0;
  $db_res = mysqli_query($db_link, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE code = '$saftycode'");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_res)){
    $check = 1;
  }
  if($check == 1){
    header('Location: home.php');
  }
}
?>
<html>
    ...
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) || isset($_POST['password'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  if($username){
    if($password){
      require("db.php");
      $saftyusername = $db_link->real_escape_string($username);
      $saftypassword = $db_link->real_escape_string($password);
      $code = null;
      $db_res = mysqli_query($db_link, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$saftyusername' AND password = '$saftypassword'");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($db_res)){
        $code = $row['code'];
      }
      if($code){
          $_SESSION['code'] = $code;
          $_SESSION['ERROR'] = "";
          header('Location:home.php');
      }else{
          $_SESSION['code'] = $code;
          $_SESSION['ERROR'] = "";
          header('Location:index.php');
      }
    }else{
      $_SESSION['ERROR'] = "";
      header('Location: index.php');
    }
  }else{
    $_SESSION['ERROR'] = "";
    header('Location: index.php');
  }
}
```

there is no session_destroy() implemented in the entire script. I actually dont know if its possible to delete a PHPSESSID cookie inside javascript, if this isnt possible i would be okay with using php for delete the cookie. Is there anyway to delete a PHPSESSID Cookie through script?, can i delete all cookies at once? these are the questions i have for you guys

> the Cookie is saved under localhost>Cookies>PHPSESSID

maybe this question is a duplicate, but i need to know how to logout users

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a variable from a PHP session array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231332/how-to-remove-a-variable-from-a-php-session-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct in saying there is no way to do this in PHP, what you can do instead if you want to remove a cookie is to set the expiry to be at a time in the past:

```php
// Set to 1 second in the past, this will invalidate the cookie.
setcookie("cookie_name", "", time() - 1, "/");
```

It is also a good idea to unset the cookie index within the `$_COOKIE` global since it can exist in there as the rest of the page is parsed.

```php
unset($_COOKIE["cookie_name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a cookie you have only set the expiry date to date before (yesterday for example)

`setcookie("sessioncookie", "", time()-3600);`